# How to exclude Header while importing data from a table in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, bigdata

I am new to PySpark, I am trying to import the data from the table which is present in Hive and storing that data into dataframe.

```
data_frame = spark.sql("Select * from table_name")
```

When I do `data_frame.show()`, I could see that it is also taking header as well and that header is acting as a row.

Can anyone help me out how to skip the header while importing the data.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have stored csv file data to your hive table. So while reading from spark you can see that header.

One simple thing you can do like

```
# Read the table data
dataFrame = spark.sql("select * from table_name")

# Convert DataFrame to RDD
rdd = dataFrame.rdd

# filter header
header = rdd.first()
newRDD = rdd.filter(lambda line: line != header)

# create the dataframe using newRDD and dataFrame schema
newDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(newRDD, dataFrame.schema)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the way you will specify that data has a header, so the first raw will be ignored.

```
spark.read.option("header", "true").load("pathToTable")
```